# What's the word for a cliche that is new?

Tags: single-word-requests, cliche

What is the word for something that is like a cliche but isn't really old yet? Some phrase, claim, or belief that is trending but is so new that you couldn't really call it cliche.

For example, often people hear things touted on the news as fact and begin repeating those things, which then become a new and commonly held belief. For example, if I were to say that the Corona virus is like the flu, everybody would quickly correct me and say that it is NOT like the flu. This claim which is new becomes widely believed, loudly defended, and often repeated. Everyone says it because everyone says it. It becomes stuck in the collective mind of the public and everyone repeats it.

Comment: A meme? Can you give an example of what you’re talking about?

Comment: @Laurel *Meme* sounds right.

Comment: "Myth" might fit the bill, but in this context it would imply that the widely held belief is inaccurate. A new phrase or newly held belief, if factual, would not be a myth.

Comment: Note that there is nothing wrong with saying "the Corona virus is like the flu", so long as you are explaining that it is, in many ways, "flu-like".  At issue is whether you stop there, or go on to explain, in more details, how it's different.

Comment: Though there's already an accepted answer, I'm wondering about *trope* here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **meme**, as suggested by @Laurel, is the best possible answer, but I'll offer up **virus**, as in going **viral**. From Cambridge:

> **[viral](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/viral)**: used to describe something that quickly becomes very popular or well known by being published on the internet or sent from person to person by email, phone, etc.:

An alternative to **virus** is **nouveaux virus**, where, as per M-W, *nouveaux* means *newly arrived or developed*. That would add to **virus** the OP's desired sense of newness.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to accept this. Something doesn't sound quite perfect to me though. Like there's another word that I can't put my finger on. But maybe this is it. Thanks!

Comment: @Benthink I don't know if you can change your acceptance, but I assume you can. You might want to wait for more answers to come in. As I said, I think *meme* is the best possible answer, but to my mind, Laurel would have to submit it based on her mention of it in her comment.

Answer (score 1):

*Meme* fits, if you go by the textbook [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme):

> A meme is an idea, behavior, or style that spreads by means of imitation from person to person within a culture and often carries symbolic meaning representing a particular phenomenon or theme.

See also [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meme).

I think I’ve heard “that’s a meme” used to refer to ideas in informal contexts. It’s hard to tell exactly, since there probably is an image macro out there for any popular piece of (mis)information.